# Fetch API with Vue Composition API (script setup)

Tags: vue.js, installation, fetch, composition

I am so confused. I want a simple generic fetch function to learn it on basic, but I want to do it with the Vue Composition API and script setup.

This is my script:

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';

const boredInfo = ref(null)

function theData(url) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(actualData => {
      console.log(actualData)
      boredInfo.value = actualData
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error('Das ist der Catch Error: ', e)
    })

  return boredInfo
}

theData('https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity')

</script>
```

This is my template

```
<template>
  <h1>Lets go!</h1>
  <div>
    <h1>Aktivität: {{boredInfo.activity}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Error I get:

```
ypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'activity')
```

JSON I get

```
{
    "activity": "Make your own LEGO creation",
    "type": "recreational",
    "participants": 1,
    "price": 0,
    "link": "",
    "key": "1129748",
    "accessibility": 0.1
}
```

As simple as that... In the whole internet I cannot find a solution for script setup, Fetch API and display the value.

But the most confusing: It shows the value! So why this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to explain why you are getting the error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'activity')`

First of all, you're trying to access a property that doesn't exist when the component is mounted, the `activity` property doesn't exist inside `boredInfo` object, so when the component is rendered it will not expect anything to want to load that property.

we can fix this in 2 ways, the first way is very simple, add the property name inside `const boredInfo = ref()`, something like this:

```
const boredInfo = ref({
  activity: ''
});
```

This setting will bypass the error.

The other option is to add a loading while the data is not yet loaded, that means that it will wait for our `theData` method to resolve, firstly a new variable is defined that will indicate the loading status:

```
const isLoading = ref(true);
```

Then we will use async/await to wait for the promise that the `fetch` method generates, and then change the load value to false, since all the data will be loaded:

```
async function theData(url) {
  try {
    isLoading.value = true;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const actualData = await response.json();
    boredInfo.value = actualData
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('Das ist der Catch Error: ', e)
  } finally {
    isLoading.value = false;
  }
};
```

And then we configure our template with a `v-if` to wait for `isLoading` to be false, to display the return value of the api:

```
<template>
    <h1>Lets go!</h1>
  <div v-if="!isLoading">
    <h1>Aktivität: {{ boredInfo.activity }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

And there you have it, that's it!

You can see the live example [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UlFu2zAMvQqrHydAYmO/mVugWPcxoEfQj+rQiTpbEijaQWD4NrvJLjbKjp1uA/qTiH7ke+QjB/UcQt53qA6qjBXZwBCRu/CknW2DJ4YBCOud/JiKbY8wQk2+hUyKsq/aaVd5FxlsfPXmaN0JHlPBhqnDreAz+uYJjz9c7W/ooB3ARGj5eoAs025M2dqZeHUV1J0T0DvgM74YNpuOmi1MVUzX+QF3zbw3TYfCnVSFJoGzMGEM8kiYuRjLUCNX54nurzzppTNNklozl9L8PXq3WdLXSVbNe2nKGKEySQFv7c4CvsEciTxtshcTpXGGIxJ8S6nwPQFiwg5wO1PU1pmm+WTO2jRxHnQU5ybjFqeyM3OIh6K4XC751K0JNq98W8h/sXieiVJZzBuXXUvA2IbGMKaIy/OXp1fkCCf/UBYSJKnyaHvo97Z+1Oph7UmrCRRY0p5/TvS/f/EBhuGDWYsujOOdrxBCeZXFqq12aj67fWvCZLwc5uSCvgFRK6GeFbWSI0yxVsvQsa7SOb/H3NOpkFdOnWPbiv2x3b+Rv0QkIdZq94GjkI890p7QyVqQPuP8J/U/3mUpavwDvJ0o4A==)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are accessing `boredInfo.activity` before your fetch has finished, when `boredInfo` is still just `ref(null)`.

Either initialize it with the expected structure, i.e.

```
const boredInfo = ref({activity: null})
```

or avoid a premature access with `v-if`, a ternary in the expression, optional chaining (`?.`), etc. Something like:

```html
<h1 v-if="boredInfo !== null">Aktivität: {{boredInfo.activity}}</h1>
```

You can show a loading spinner while loading, that's always nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget that the code below :

```
<template>
 <h1>Lets go!</h1>
 <div>
  <h1>Aktivität: {{boredInfo.activity}}</h1>
 </div>
</template>
```

It has called before your api call is done. so... the simple solution is you can add **v-if** inside the div or h1 to check is variable has filled by the api response. Thats the main problem, so the solution it can be more variety depends yours.